# Generating a new ServiceStack React Project is missing SharpPagesFeature

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, servicestack

I updated to the latest @servicestack/cli

```
npm install -g @servicestack/cli
+ @servicestack/cli@1.0.8
updated 5 packages in 5.862s
```

Ran the dotnet-new command:

```
C:\Projects\Personal> dotnet-new react-spa POETS

> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall C:\Projects\Personal\POETS\POETS\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> node lib/post_install.js


> poets@0.1.0 postinstall C:\Projects\Personal\POETS\POETS
> npm run build


> poets@0.1.0 build C:\Projects\Personal\POETS\POETS
> rimraf wwwroot/ && react-scripts-ts build && (move build wwwroot || mv build wwwroot)

Creating an optimized production build...
Starting type checking and linting service...
Using 1 worker with 2048MB memory limit
ts-loader: Using typescript@3.2.4 and C:\Projects\Personal\POETS\POETS\tsconfig.prod.json
Compiled successfully.

File sizes after gzip:

  80.72 KB  build\static\js\main.5832e8d6.js
  29.7 KB   build\static\css\main.4df18a76.css

The project was built assuming it is hosted at the server root.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
For example, add this to build it for GitHub Pages:

  "homepage" : "http://myname.github.io/myapp",

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

  npm install -g serve
  serve -s build



        1 dir(s) moved.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

added 1564 packages in 27.283s
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '16.0.360.33175' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\MSBuild\Current\bin'.
Restoring packages for C:\Projects\Personal\POETS\POETS.ServiceInterface\POETS.ServiceInterface.csproj...
Restoring packages for C:\Projects\Personal\POETS\POETS.Tests\POETS.Tests.csproj...
Restoring packages for C:\Projects\Personal\POETS\POETS\POETS.csproj...
Restoring packages for C:\Projects\Personal\POETS\POETS.ServiceModel\POETS.ServiceModel.csproj...
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/servicestack.kestrel/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/servicestack/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/nunit/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.test.sdk/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/nunit3testadapter/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/servicestack.interfaces/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/servicestack.kestrel/index.json 194ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/servicestack.kestrel/5.4.0/servicestack.kestrel.5.4.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/nunit/index.json 237ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.test.sdk/index.json 246ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/nunit3testadapter/index.json 248ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/servicestack.interfaces/index.json 263ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/servicestack.interfaces/5.4.0/servicestack.interfaces.5.4.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/servicestack/index.json 318ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/servicestack/5.4.0/servicestack.5.4.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/servicestack.kestrel/5.4.0/servicestack.kestrel.5.4.0.nupkg 162ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/servicestack.interfaces/5.4.0/servicestack.interfaces.5.4.0.nupkg 149ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/servicestack/5.4.0/servicestack.5.4.0.nupkg 151ms
Installing ServiceStack.Interfaces 5.4.0.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/servicestack.client/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/servicestack.common/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/servicestack.client/index.json 158ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/servicestack.client/5.4.0/servicestack.client.5.4.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/servicestack.common/index.json 173ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/servicestack.common/5.4.0/servicestack.common.5.4.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/servicestack.client/5.4.0/servicestack.client.5.4.0.nupkg 148ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/servicestack.common/5.4.0/servicestack.common.5.4.0.nupkg 146ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/servicestack.text/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/servicestack.text/index.json 159ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/servicestack.text/5.4.0/servicestack.text.5.4.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/servicestack.text/5.4.0/servicestack.text.5.4.0.nupkg 162ms
Committing restore...
Generating MSBuild file C:\Projects\Personal\POETS\POETS.ServiceModel\obj\POETS.ServiceModel.csproj.nuget.g.props.
Generating MSBuild file C:\Projects\Personal\POETS\POETS.ServiceModel\obj\POETS.ServiceModel.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
Writing lock file to disk. Path: C:\Projects\Personal\POETS\POETS.ServiceModel\obj\project.assets.json
Restore completed in 1.79 sec for C:\Projects\Personal\POETS\POETS.ServiceModel\POETS.ServiceModel.csproj.
Installing ServiceStack.Text 5.4.0.
Installing ServiceStack.Client 5.4.0.
Installing ServiceStack.Common 5.4.0.
Installing ServiceStack 5.4.0.
Installing ServiceStack.Kestrel 5.4.0.
Committing restore...
Generating MSBuild file C:\Projects\Personal\POETS\POETS.ServiceInterface\obj\POETS.ServiceInterface.csproj.nuget.g.props.
Generating MSBuild file C:\Projects\Personal\POETS\POETS.ServiceInterface\obj\POETS.ServiceInterface.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
Writing lock file to disk. Path: C:\Projects\Personal\POETS\POETS.ServiceInterface\obj\project.assets.json
Restore completed in 2.82 sec for C:\Projects\Personal\POETS\POETS.ServiceInterface\POETS.ServiceInterface.csproj.
Committing restore...
Generating MSBuild file C:\Projects\Personal\POETS\POETS.Tests\obj\POETS.Tests.csproj.nuget.g.props.
Generating MSBuild file C:\Projects\Personal\POETS\POETS.Tests\obj\POETS.Tests.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
Writing lock file to disk. Path: C:\Projects\Personal\POETS\POETS.Tests\obj\project.assets.json
Restore completed in 2.84 sec for C:\Projects\Personal\POETS\POETS.Tests\POETS.Tests.csproj.
Committing restore...
Generating MSBuild file C:\Projects\Personal\POETS\POETS\obj\POETS.csproj.nuget.g.props.
Generating MSBuild file C:\Projects\Personal\POETS\POETS\obj\POETS.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
Writing lock file to disk. Path: C:\Projects\Personal\POETS\POETS\obj\project.assets.json
Restore completed in 2.86 sec for C:\Projects\Personal\POETS\POETS\POETS.csproj.

NuGet Config files used:
    C:\Projects\Personal\POETS\NuGet.Config
    C:\Users\willi\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
    C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config

Feeds used:
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Installed:
    1 package(s) to C:\Projects\Personal\POETS\POETS.ServiceModel\POETS.ServiceModel.csproj
    5 package(s) to C:\Projects\Personal\POETS\POETS.ServiceInterface\POETS.ServiceInterface.csproj
    6 package(s) to C:\Projects\Personal\POETS\POETS.Tests\POETS.Tests.csproj
    5 package(s) to C:\Projects\Personal\POETS\POETS\POETS.csproj
```

Opened the App in Visual Studio 2017, and have a missing dependency for SharpPagesFeature.

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        Plugins.Add(new SharpPagesFeature()); // <--- Can't resolve this

        SetConfig(new HostConfig
        {
            AddRedirectParamsToQueryString = true,
            DebugMode = AppSettings.Get(nameof(HostConfig.DebugMode), false)
        });
    }
```

Does anyone know what package this is from? I see on GitHub that SharpPagesFeature is in the main namespace (ServiceStack).

**EDIT**

Additionally, the generated MyService.cs has incorrect dependencies and missing imports:

```
using ServiceStack.Script; <--- this can't be resolved and is unused

new PageResult(Request.GetPage("/")); <-- this requires me to import ServiceStack.Templates.PageResult (which resolves fine)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an old [pre-release v5.4.1 of ServiceStack](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget) installed.

You'll need to [clear your NuGet packages cache](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget#redownloading-myget-packages) to install the latest version, e.g:

```
$ nuget locals all -clear
```

Comment: The only issue I see, after digging through the SS CLI's code, is that the latest NPM SS CLI is pulling V19 of react-spa from GitHub, which has this SharpPagesFeature. This version of react-spa was released on 03/05/2019. The V18 react-spa, that was released on 1/19/2019 uses the TemplatePagesFeature (that works). Could you have accidentally released a new react-spa that is based on a pre-release version of SS?

Comment: @Jack it’s definitely because you’re referencing stale v5.4.1 packages and need to clear your NuGet packages cache in order to download the latest v5.4.1, I already have deployed Apps using these classes, you’re using old pre v5.4.1 packages

Comment: For anyone else who might struggle with this issue (and it still doesn't work even after clearing your NuGet cache): Update your NuGet version to the latest. I was using a version from June / July of 2018. After downloading the latest, `nuget locals all -clear` appears to clear another cache.